# How to redirect stderr in a variable but keep stdout in the console

Tags: bash, terminal, variable, stdout, stderr

My goal is to call a command, get stderr in a variable, but keep stdout (and only stdout) on the screen. Yep, that's the opposite of what most people do :)

For the moment, the best I have is :

```
#!/bin/bash
pull=$(sudo ./pull "${TAG}" 2>&1)
pull_code=$?

if [[ ! "${pull_code}" -eq 0 ]]; then
  error "[${pull_code}] ${pull}"
  exit "${E_PULL_FAILED}"
fi

echo "${pull}"
```

But this can only show the stdout in case of success, and after the command finish. I want to have stdout on live, is this possible ?

**EDIT**

Thanks to @sebasth, and with the help of [Redirect STDERR and STDOUT to different variables without temporary files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/430161/redirect-stderr-and-stdout-to-different-variables-without-temporary-files), I write this :

```
#!/bin/bash
{
  sudo ./pull "${TAG}" 2> /dev/fd/3
  pull_code=$?
  if [[ ! "${pull_code}" -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "[${pull_code}] $(cat<&3)"
    exit "${E_PULL_FAILED}"
  fi
} 3<<EOF
EOF
```

I admit this not really "beautiful", seems tricky, and I don't really understand why the heredoc is needed...

Is this the better way to achieve that ?

Comment: Not really, if I redirect stdout in A and stderr in B, I can independently print A or B but when the command is already finished. I want A printed as the command processes ; did I miss something ?

Comment: You can use the same answer, just do not redirect stdout.

Comment: No, not duplicate of [Redirect STDERR and STDOUT to different variables without temporary files](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/430161). It's much simpler here. (there probably is a different duplicate somewhere though).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just use:

```
{ err=$(cmd 2>&1 >&3 3>&-); } 3>&1
```

To get the stderr of `cmd` while leaving its stdout untouched (here by using fd 3 to *bring* the original stdout (copied with `3>&1`) inside the command substitution (restored with `>&3` after we've redirected fd 2 to the pipe created by the command substitution with `2>&1`)).

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks. I enjoy the use of the word "Just" to introduce this bit of syntax.

Comment: I think the `3>&1` should instead happen before as `exec 3>&1` followed by a `exec 3>&-` at the end.
The reason is that, if no command name results (which is the case here), POSIX leaves the order in which redirections and assignments happen open. See (2.9.1 Simple Commands).

Comment: @calestyo, here we have a compound command (a command group) with redirection. Inside that we have a simple-command with assignment, no command, no redirection. The value of the assignment is a command substitution, inside we have another simple command with a command, redirection and no assignment. The text you're refering to would apply if it was the `err=...` assignment we were redirecting as in `err=$(...) 3>&1`, but here it's a command group we're redirecting

Comment: I see, so it's basically just the grouping command, which does the trick?! And since one can always just put a single assignment inside { var=val; }, one never really needs to use `exec` there for that niche case, but can just directly redirect?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the answer provided by [Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/430182/239817) with minor modifications: only redirect stderr and do not use command substitution to run your command.

```
{
  command 2> /dev/fd/3
  res=$?
  err=$(cat<&3)
} 3<<EOF
EOF

printf 'stderr: %s\n' "$err"
```

Output of `command` will be normally in stdout and stderr is in `err` variable.

Comment: Ah, you wrote this while I was editing my questions ^^ - mark a accepted answer, but I'm waiting to see if there is a less complicated way :)

Comment: That convoluted stuff in the other answer was because we needed a temp file there. We don't need one here as we don't need stdout and stderr in different variables. As noted there, it's shell and OS dependent.

Answer (score 1):

Just exchange stdout and stderr for the command to capture stderr.

```
pull=$(sudo ./pull "${TAG}" 3>&2 2>&1 1>&3)
```

And then redirect stderr back to stdout:

```
{ pull=$(sudo ./pull "${TAG}" 3>&2 2>&1 1>&3; } 2>&1
```

Explanation:

In the same way as when you capture only stdout of a command:

```
var=$(cmd)
```

the output of stderr still goes to the command line. You can swap both channels to capture only the stderr:

```
var=$(cmd 3>&2 2>&1 1>&3)
```

And then, redirect the stderr back to stdout (to show the output (if any)).

```
{ var=$(f 3>&2 2>&1 1>&3); }  2>&1
```

Answer (score 1):

Combining answers from both [How to output to screen overriding redirection](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107861/how-to-output-to-screen-overriding-redirection) and [How to capture stderr of a bash keyword (e.g. time)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/429547/how-to-capture-stderr-of-a-bash-keyword-e-g-time), I get

```
var=$( (cmd >/dev/tty) 2>&1)
```

If you're not using a builtin or keyword, that simplifies to

```
var=$( cmd 2>&1 >/dev/tty )
```