# SSH - print an input prompt to terminal overriding redirection

Tags: bash, ssh, io-redirection, prompt

I have two scripts:

- `test_input.sh` is a script which is executed through SSH. In this script I ask the user for something in input.
- `test_ssh_connection.sh` is a script which connects to `localhost` and executes the script `test_input.sh`

In `test_ssh_connection.sh` I want to redirect the output of `test_input.sh` to a file, but in `test_input.sh` I want to display on screen the input prompt, becuase I want to be able to see that prompt.

This is my `test_ssh_connection.sh`:

```
echo "Connecting to localhost and executing an input script."
ssh "localhost" "sh test_input.sh" >> "test.txt"
```

this is `test_input.sh`:

```
echo -n "Give me a value: "
read value
echo "You gave me [${value}]."
```

Actually, this is the content of `test.txt` after executing `test_ssh_connection.sh`:

```
Give me a value: You gave me [asd].
```

Currently, the prompt `Give me a value:` is only in `test.txt` and not in terminal. Instead, what I want is to display it in the terminal and, if it's possibile, I would like to remove it from `test.txt`.

I've found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107861/how-to-output-to-screen-overriding-redirection) question, but it seems that if the subscript is called through ssh `>/dev/tty`/`>$(tty)` do not work.

Comment: Welcome on U&L! Have you tried without the `-t` option to `ssh`? Do you have any specific reason for using it?

Comment: @fra-san I've added that option because otherwise I get this error if I use `>/dev/tty` redirection: `test_input.sh: line 1: /dev/tty: No such device or address`. Anyway, I've tried to remove it but the script is still showing the prompt only on the file and not in the terminal.
I've updated my question.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I missed that bit. You may use `echo -n "Give me a value: " >&2`, printing messages to the user on standard error. In this test case it should do what you are asking for.

Comment: @fra-san yes, it works, but is there another way? I would like to keep stderr for messages that are really **errors**

Comment: The limitation you face is that `ssh` only provides you with three streams. While you can `exec 4>&1; echo prompt >&4; ...` to have a _local_ script prompt to the terminal while redirecting its stdout to a file, you cannot have `ssh` client pass further file descriptors to the server. The remote script only has stdout and stderr to send data to your local shell. Forcing terminal allocation with `-t` is not a solution because it still doesn't allow you to separate ordinary output and prompts to the user. You may work around this, but I think the good advice is that in Kusalananda's answer.

Comment: @fra-san thank you for your help too, I've decided to use the standard error stream as you initially suggested :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prompts and other interactive messages that are not part of an application's ordinary output are usually written to the standard error stream for this very reason.  It is, for example, to the shell's standard error stream that the primary prompt is written.

The `read` utility in `bash` will display the prompt on standard error when given with `-p`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

read -r -p 'Give me a value: ' value
printf 'You gave me [%s].\n' "$value"
```

With `/bin/sh` you would do something like

```sh
#!/bin/sh

printf 'Give me a value: ' >&2
read -r value
printf 'You gave me [%s].\n' "$value"
```

The redirection `>&2` will redirect the output of `printf` to standard error.

Related:

- [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803)

---

Would you want to write *directly to the TTY*, then use the second of these two variations and redirect the prompt message with `>/dev/tty`.  Note that you will have to use `ssh -t` to allocate a pseudo-TTY for this to work.  Also note that you are breaking a fairly common custom by not using standard error for prompting if you do this.

Comment: I've always thought that the standard error should be used for messages that are errors... but now I realized that I've always thought wrong.

Comment: @Riccardo If you mispronounce standard error as  "standard other", it would more accurately describe its purpose.